# Чем кроме WM_SIZE обработать изменение размера окна?

Tags: winapi

Мне нужно, чтобы когда я "растягиваю" окно, оно постоянно перерисовывалось, а не когда я мышку отпускаю.

Answer (score 2):

Изменение размеров окна ничем, кроме WM_SIZE обрабатывать просто не нужно. Это сообщение специально сделано для уведомления вашей оконной процедуры об изменении размеров окна.

А описанная вами проблема действительно устраняется настройками операционной системы. Кстати, не помешало бы и её уточнить в вопросе. Настройка "Отображать содержимое окна при перетаскивании". Для Windows 7: ***Мой компьютер -> Свойства -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Визуальные эффекты -> Отображать содержимое окна при перетаскивании***.

Также включить эту настрйку можно программно функцией [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx). Но не советовал бы её использовать. Вряд ли кому-то понравится программа, котоая меняет системные настройки для своей работы.

Answer (score 1):

А когда вы "растягиваете" окно, перерисовывается только его рамка или все окно, но "мусором"?

Если первое, то смотрите настройки винды (флаг называется как-то так: "перерисовывать окно при перемещении").

Если второе, то в событии `WM_MOUSEMOVE` можно проверять, нажата ли левая кн. мыши и делать вызовы `invalidate()\update()`.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под настройками винды?)

Comment: в настройках экрана ОС поставить флаг "Перерисовывать содержимое окна при перетаскивании"

Answer (score 0):

Для этого логично использовать "кэтчер" событий в APIENTRY-функции WinMain() :

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, вам нужно [`WM_SIZING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Это сообщение посылается время от времени, когда окно находится *в процессе* изменения размера.